# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named" while using python in c++ project

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to use python in C++ project to access SSH, everything is working until I have to import module.
If I'm using just simple Py_Initialize; PyRun_SimpleString(print('lol'); Py_Finalize();
it will show it without any problems, but when it comes to part when I have to import module "Paramiko" everything is broken.

CPP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();

    std::string username;
    std::cout << "Enter the username: ";
    std::cin >> username;

    wchar_t* program_name = Py_DecodeLocale("program_name", NULL);
    wchar_t* username_wide = Py_DecodeLocale(username.c_str(), NULL);
    PySys_SetObject("argv", Py_BuildValue("[is]", program_name, username_wide));

    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("ssh_script");
    if (pModule != NULL) {
        PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "execute_ssh_command");
        if (pFunc != NULL && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(username.c_str()));
            PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_XDECREF(pArgs);
            Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        } else {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    } else {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(program_name);
    PyMem_RawFree(username_wide);

    return 0;
}
```

Python:

```
import sys
import paramiko

def execute_ssh_command():
    hostname = '****'
    username = '****'
    password = '****'
    port = 21098 
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()

        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        client.connect(hostname, port, username, password)

        command_cd = 'cd www && ./check-sub.sh mcs'
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command_cd)

        print(stdout.read().decode())

        client.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error executing SSH command: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_ssh_command()
```

Script by itself is working, when I do "python 123.py" it shows what I want.

That's the output by script itself: https://imgur.com/a/IIQ3TYS

But that's output in C++ project: https://imgur.com/a/e525IeD

I've tried alot, looking around forums, discords, AI - almost everything but nothing is working.